# Correspondence between information theoretic and coding theoretic language?

Tags: it.information-theory, coding-theory

In information theory capacity or best rate achievement techniques are through showing existence if typical sequences of certain measure while in coding theory performance is measured by number of codewords of minimum weight and minimum weight. What are some of the correspondences between information theoretic and coding theoretic language that may Illuminate relation between achievability and design?